# Why do I need to add the line "android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents" in order for my FloatingActionButton to work?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, material-components-android

I'm inflating a layout using layout Inflater

My theme is already `MaterialComponents`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

But when I try to inflate the layout with this `FAB`,

`R.layout.test_view`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
view = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_view, null);
```

It's throwing the errors

`Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`

`The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).`

The above error doesn't make sense to me either because the `FAB` is material, not appcompat.

Unless I add this line:

`android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents" 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Why do I need this line when my entire app theme is already set as `Material` for the application in my manifest?

`<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: The `android:theme` attribute on the `<application>` element simply serves to set a default theme for the `Activity` classes. It doesn't set that theme on every `Context` everywhere in your app, so the `LayoutInflater` in your (presumably) `Service` doesn't have that theme by default.

Comment: wow I didn't know this, thanks for explaining! And yes I'm trying to inflate it in a service